# Sign-in user will never see the Login page again unless Logout. Asp.net core (2.1 or 2.2 or 3.0)

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-identity

I want to fix an issue where the sign-in user will never see the login page again unless he/she logout. How can i do it in asp.net core 2.2 identity razor page???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to fix an issue where the sign-in user will never see the login page again unless he/she logout. How can i do it in asp.net core 2.2 identity razor page???

To achieve above requirement, you can create and use a custom  [Razor Page filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/filter?view=aspnetcore-3.1#implement-razor-page-filters-globally) to check request path and current user login status, like blow.

```
public Task OnPageHandlerSelectionAsync(PageHandlerSelectedContext context)
{
    if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path == "/Identity/Account/Login"&& context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        //redirect to index page
        context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/");
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```